# C# SSL server mode must use a certificate with the corresponding private key

Tags: c#, ssl, https, x509certificate, handle

I'm going to learn how to handle HTTPS traffic in C# as server-side and as for the first steps I've got some troubles.

Here is some code ( http://pastebin.com/C4ZYrS8Q ):

```
class Program
{
    static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None) return true;
        Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
        return false;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
        tcpListener.Start();
        var clientAccept = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        if (clientAccept.Available > 0)
        {
            var sslStream = new SslStream(clientAccept.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
            var certificate = new X509Certificate("path\server.pfx", "password");
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Don't argue! :) It's the test code only where I just want to achieve some basic steps with the SSL handling in C#.

So... The problem occurs at this line:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate);
```

[image]

From Russian it translates as:

- **SSL server mode must use a certificate with the corresponding private key.**

I thought, that I've made my X509 certificate incorrect, but checked again:

```
makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=localhost" -sky exchange -sv server.pvk server.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx -pi <password>
```

And seems to be that all is fine with the X509 creation, and other proof is this line works fine:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate("path\server.pfx", "password");
```

And program didn't throw an exception on the line above.

So, what's the problem with the SSL hanlding in my code and how can I handle incoming SSL stream as server-side?

Comment: What does the client to communicate with server using SSL? Show client code.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan simply browser Chrome, it's the client, with using `https://` URI

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All is fine, the answer is to use `X509Certificate2` class instead of `X509Certificate`.

And to add to the trust list your created certificate.